# How to change default view of library using javascript or programatically?

Tags: 2010, list, javascript, list-view

I have a requirement where I have to change view based on users logged into the portal. If user belongs to guest view then view should be different and if he is logged in as admin a different view should be displayed. I want to do that by changing the default view to the view I have created. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This code change the view by taking the id of the new view by list. (you can use your own logic to change it)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//declare a variable for the exisitng view
var existingview;

function loadViewAndChangeIfExists()
{
  //get the current client context
  clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  //if the client context exists - proceed
  if (clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
    //get the current web
    var web = clientContext.get_web();
    //get all lists
    var listCollection = web.get_lists();
    //get te current list by name - alternative use getById(guid)
    var list = listCollection.getByTitle("COM");
    //get all current views of the list
    var viewcollection = list.get_views();
    //get the view that you will change
    this.existingview = viewcollection.getByTitle("MYVIEW");
    //load your existing view and execute async
    clientContext.load(existingview);
    //the asynchronous execution will try to load the existing view
    //if the view does not exist - it will call onQueryFailed - else it will call changeView
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.changeView), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
  }
}

function changeView() {
  //the varible existingview is now loaded with your view
  //get the current CAML query
  var existingquery = existingview.get_viewQuery();
  //do somnething with the exisitng query here
  //...
  //reset the query (as sample)
  existingquery = "<Where><In><FieldRef Name="ID" /><Values>";
  //add a CAML filter with the current selected items
  var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
  var i;
  for (i in selectedItems) {
    existingquery += "<Value Type="Counter">" + selectedItems[i].id + "</Value>"; //add
  }
  //close the CAML XML
  existingquery += "</Values></In></Where>";
  //assocciate the existing view with the changed query
  existingview.set_viewQuery(existingquery);
  //update the view!!!
  existingview.update();
  //execute the statements async - onQuerySucceeded for success - onQueryFailed for errors
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
  //show error message ()stacktrace
  alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 'n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
//show successful message
alert('View successfully changed!');
}
</script>
```

[Changing existing list views](http://blog.avanade.com/asg-collaboration-services/developement/client-object-model-changing-list-views/)

Comment: I don't want to redirect the user. I just want to change the view even if it changes  for all users.  I have separate function to check for the user's group.

Comment: updated my answer